# Access ECT from a Sharepoint hosted app

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin

how to access a list with External content Type.
I have permission problems if I try  to do it
with SP.RequestExecutor like explained in [this article](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/accessing-bcs-external-data-from-an-app-for-sharepoint-2013/).
The author suggests "package your External Content Type in the SPAPP as well"

But how? Have you got any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One of the new things about the External List in SharePoint 2013 is
>   the ability to create external content types that are scoped at the
>   app level in SharePoint 2013. In other words Business Connectivity
>   Data models can be scoped to apps for SharePoint so you don’t have to
>   deploy External Content Type  to the Farm and you don’t have to
>   involve an administrator in order to access Business Connectivity
>   Service in the Farm. Farm level External Content Types work great for
>   farm solutions but this approach is not applicable for apps in
>   SharePoint 2013 as app is an isolated. So another reason for adding an
>   app-scoped external content type is to provide access to external data
>   from an individual app. For Apps, BDC model is stored in a file in a
>   document library rather than in BDC metadata store. When the app is
>   run SharePoint uses FileBackedMetdataCataog to read metadata from this
>   file into in-memory BDC runtime which can be read by an external list
>   then. This BDC runtime can work with ECTs based on MS SQL, WCF/Web
>   services and OData . Custom connectors and .net assembly connectors
>   cannot be used along with this runtime BDC and hence with App level
>   ECTs.

See these links for more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/10/24/using-an-odata-service-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx

http://lightningtools.com/bcs/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint-2013-app-scoped-external-content-types/